# dmesg is flooding with lines as SELinux: initialized

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, selinux, dmesg

on our rhel 7.x machines we have run `dmesg` but we get all log as

```
[12283.628766] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
[12286.352175] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
[12289.207620] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
[12291.932644] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
[12294.924467] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
[12297.758151] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
[12300.449455] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
```

.
.
.

the `sestatus` is

```
sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          disabled
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

for now we actually disabled the selinux as

```
more /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

so as I understand `permissive` mode is similar to disabled

any suggestion how to stop flooding the `dmesg` with all these lines?

Comment: No suggestion, but a data point: The problem was discussed on the kernel mailing list six years ago: https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/1/8/468. Probably caused by systemd creating tmpfs filesystems for each new session.

Comment: permissive is more similar to enforced when it comes to dmesg logs